# Want to generate databricks notebook URL to send alerts

Tags: python, azure, databricks

```
def _get_dbutils():
    try:
        import IPython

        ip_shell = IPython.get_ipython()
        if ip_shell is None:
            raise _NoDbutilsError
        return ip_shell.ns_table["user_global"]["dbutils"]
    except ImportError:
        raise _NoDbutilsError
    except KeyError:
        raise _NoDbutilsError


class _NoDbutilsError(Exception):
    pass


def _get_java_dbutils():
    dbutils = _get_dbutils()
    return dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils()


def _get_command_context():
    return _get_java_dbutils().notebook().getContext()


def _get_extra_context(context_key):
    return _get_command_context().extraContext().get(context_key).get()


def _get_context_tag(context_tag_key):
    tag_opt = _get_command_context().tags().get(context_tag_key)
    if tag_opt.isDefined():
        return tag_opt.get()
    else:
        return None


def acl_path_of_acl_root():
    try:
        return _get_command_context().aclPathOfAclRoot().get()
    except Exception:
        return _get_extra_context("aclPathOfAclRoot")


def _get_property_from_spark_context(key):
    try:
        from pyspark import TaskContext  # pylint: disable=import-error

        task_context = TaskContext.get()
        if task_context:
            return task_context.getLocalProperty(key)
    except Exception:
        return None


def is_databricks_default_tracking_uri(tracking_uri):
    return tracking_uri.lower().strip() == "databricks"


def is_in_databricks_notebook():
    if _get_property_from_spark_context("spark.databricks.notebook.id") is not None:
        return True
    try:
        return acl_path_of_acl_root().startswith("/workspace")
    except Exception:
        return False


def is_in_databricks_job():
    try:
        return get_job_id() is not None and get_job_run_id() is not None
    except Exception:
        return False


def is_in_databricks_runtime():
    try:
        # pylint: disable=unused-import,import-error,no-name-in-module,unused-variable
        import pyspark.databricks

        return True
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        return False


def is_dbfs_fuse_available():
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull_stderr, open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull_stdout:
        try:
            return (
                subprocess.call(
                    ["mountpoint", "/dbfs"], stderr=devnull_stderr, stdout=devnull_stdout
                )
                == 0
            )
        except Exception:
            return False


def is_in_cluster():
    try:
        spark_session = _get_active_spark_session()
        return (
            spark_session is not None
            and spark_session.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterId") is not None
        )
    except Exception:
        return False


def get_notebook_id():
    """Should only be called if is_in_databricks_notebook is true"""
    notebook_id = _get_property_from_spark_context("spark.databricks.notebook.id")
    if notebook_id is not None:
        return notebook_id
    acl_path = acl_path_of_acl_root()
    if acl_path.startswith("/workspace"):
        return acl_path.split("/")[-1]
    return None


def get_notebook_path():
    """Should only be called if is_in_databricks_notebook is true"""
    path = _get_property_from_spark_context("spark.databricks.notebook.path")
    if path is not None:
        return path
    try:
        return _get_command_context().notebookPath().get()
    except Exception:
        return _get_extra_context("notebook_path")


def get_databricks_runtime():
    if is_in_databricks_runtime():
        spark_session = _get_active_spark_session()
        if spark_session is not None:
            return spark_session.conf.get(
                "spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.sparkVersion", default=None
            )
    return None


def get_cluster_id():
    spark_session = _get_active_spark_session()
    if spark_session is None:
        return None
    return spark_session.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterId")


def get_job_group_id():
    try:
        dbutils = _get_dbutils()
        job_group_id = dbutils.entry_point.getJobGroupId()
        if job_group_id is not None:
            return job_group_id
    except Exception:
        return None


def get_job_id():
    try:
        return _get_command_context().jobId().get()
    except Exception:
        return _get_context_tag("jobId")


def get_job_run_id():
    try:
        return _get_command_context().idInJob().get()
    except Exception:
        return _get_context_tag("idInJob")


def get_job_type():
    """Should only be called if is_in_databricks_job is true"""
    try:
        return _get_command_context().jobTaskType().get()
    except Exception:
        return _get_context_tag("jobTaskType")


def get_command_run_id():
    try:
        return _get_command_context().commandRunId().get()
    except Exception:
        # Older runtimes may not have the commandRunId available
        return None


def get_webapp_url():
    """Should only be called if is_in_databricks_notebook or is_in_databricks_jobs is true"""
    url = _get_property_from_spark_context("spark.databricks.api.url")
    if url is not None:
        return url
    try:
        return _get_command_context().apiUrl().get()
    except Exception:
        return _get_extra_context("api_url")


def get_workspace_id():
    try:
        return _get_command_context().workspaceId().get()
    except Exception:
        return _get_context_tag("orgId")


def get_browser_hostname():
    try:
        return _get_command_context().browserHostName().get()
    except Exception:
        return _get_context_tag("browserHostName")


def get_workspace_info_from_dbutils():
    dbutils = _get_dbutils()
    if dbutils:
        browser_hostname = get_browser_hostname()
        workspace_host = "https://" + browser_hostname if browser_hostname else get_webapp_url()
        workspace_id = get_workspace_id()
        browserHash=_get_context_tag('browserHash')        
        return workspace_host+'/?o='+workspace_id+browserHash
    return None, None
```

**This code helps me generate notebook URL when I call get_workspace_info_from_dbutils()

I get
https://odyssey-lakehouse-dev-bronze.cloud.databricks.com/?o=7808874896028593#notebook/3018684734636397/command/3018684734636399

But when I run the same notebook as a job in databricks, the browsrhostname and browserhash doesnt get generated
and I get something like this
'https://ireland.cloud.databricks.com/?o=7808874896028593#/api/2.0/workspace/get-notebook-snapshot' **

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting `browserhostname` and `browserhash` probably because when it runs as a job, it doesn't have a notebook interface in the browser. Instead, the code just gets executed in the cluster (which is probably the url you are getting).

Since notebooks generally reside inside a workspace/databricks account, you can have the hostname and the workspace id as a constant. You can try getting the notebook information for a job using the [Jobs API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsGet) and then use the [Workspace API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html) to get the rest of the information.